# C# Detecting Input Device

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have wireless USB Bar-code Scanner and I made an application That get the values from bar-code scanner and Store values in Data base It ok.. 
Now the Problem is The Application need to Detect that the input coming from either bar-code or key board.

The one barcode cradle can manage more than one Scanner. timer is useless

can someone help me..

The Code is below

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

char[] keyws = new char[50];
                int count = 0;

```
            private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    String s = new String(keyws);
                    label1.Text = s;

                    count = 0;
                    if (keyws[0] == 13)
                    {
                        label2.Text = s.Substring(1, 4);
                        label3.Text = s.Substring(5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label2.Text = s.Substring(0, 4);
                        label3.Text = s.Substring(4);
                    }

                    Array.Clear(keyws, 0, keyws.Length);
                    try
                    {
                        int state = 0;

                        DBConnection con = new DBConnection();
                        state=con.insertData(label3.Text, "50");
                        if (state!=1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    String s2 = new String(keyws);
                    label1.Text = s2;
                }
            }

            private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {

                keyws[count] = e.KeyChar;
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trap keystrokes in your form control and check **KeyUp**, **KeyDown** and **KeyPress** events to see if there is any difference when data comes from the keyboard or from the barcode scanner. See this link as a guideline:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320584/en-us

Comment: Is there a way to disable bar-code device..?

Comment: Page is no longer available